Finding Elementary Divisors and Invariant Factors for Module
I wanted to run my solution for this problem by some of y'all and make sure I have the hang of this:
If D=K[x], where K is a field, let A be a K[x]-module such that $$A \cong \frac{K[x]}{(x-2)^3} \oplus \frac{K[x]}{(x-5)} \oplus \frac{K[x]}{(x-3)^2} \oplus \frac{K[x]}{(x-2)^4(x-3)}$$
Would the elementary divisors be $(x-2)$ (mult. 7), $(x-5)$ (mult. 1), and $(x-3)$ (mult. 3)?
Would the invariant factors be $(x-2)^3, (x-5), (x-3)^2, (x-2)^4(x-3)$?
Thanks :)

Note that you can split the last summand further by applying the Chinese remainder theorem.
